# Does declare -u in bash also make variables locally scoped?

Tags: bash

I'm mystified by the output of this example script.  It seems as if some_other_var is being implicitly declared as local when I declare it as uppercase (declare -u):

```
#!/bin/bash

function works() {
    some_var="${1}"
    printf "in the function, some_var is ${some_var}\n"
}

function doesnt_work() {
    declare -u some_other_var="${1}"
    printf "in the function, some_other_var is ${some_other_var}\n"
}

works "apple"
printf "got back this value of some_var from the function: ${some_var}\n"

doesnt_work "banana"
printf "got back this value of some_other_var from the function: ${some_other_var}\n"
```

Output:

```
in the function, some_var is apple
got back this value of some_var from the function: apple
in the function, some_other_var is BANANA
got back this value of some_other_var from the function:
```

declare -u is supposed to make the variable uppercase-only, which it does.  But is it supposed to also make a variable locally scoped?  I was under the impression that one had to use the 'local' directive to explicitly mark a variable as local, otherwise it was global, but declare -u seems to behave differently.

This is:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a general property of `declare`: when used in a function, it implies local scope. To use global scope, the `-g` flag (Bash 4.2+) has to be used.

See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare):

> When used in a function, `declare` makes each *name* local, as with the `local` command, unless the `-g` option is used.

Comment: The OP is in luck, as the `-g` option was added to `bash` in version 4.2 :)